# spring-kafka - When there are multiple failed records from different partitions seekToCurrentErrorHandler behaves random and consumer leaves broker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am looking into recovering error records using a custom recoverer with seekToCurrentErrorHandler.
We are using spring-kafka version 2.2.6-RELEASE (with spring-boot) in our project. Saw that (and faced the issue) in case of a single consumer (and concurrency 1) with multiple failed records from different partitions it ends up in infinite loop ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1237)
As its fixed in later versions, have switched to 2.3.3-RELEASE, and ended up facing another issue described below (tried version 2.5.4-RELEASE as well, ending up in same issue).

So with spring-kafka 2.3.3-RELEASE or 2.5.4-RELEASE below is the issue we are facing.

When a single kafka consumer is brought up with 6 records to be consumed from a topic (with 3 partitions, 2 records on each partition)
and when all of them result in failure (@KafkaListener annotated method throwing a runtimeException)
listener (i.e. @KafkaListener annotated method) gets invoked for 2 or 3 records (random), does retries as expected (5 retires + 1 original failure) and recoverer gets invoked for those records
and for  3rd or 4th record about 3 times retry is attempted and after about 5mins (which is default max.poll.interval.ms ) consumer disconnects from broker (doesn't process rest of the 3 records) .
Also when 3 records are processed, only 2 are committed (i.e. next time when app is started, listener is again invoked with already processed 3rd record)
Below is the configuration.
Could be replicated with JUNIT as well.
Please let me know if I am missing something here.!!
Can we not use only seekToCurrentErrorHandler with recoverer in case of multiple failed records from different partitions? or we have to use stateful retry with RecoveryCallback only ?(tried that as well and saw same issue) ?

```java
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) throws IOException{
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommitTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2000));
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(processingFailedErrorRecoverer(),new FixedBackOff(0L,5L));
        seekToCurrentErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(seekToCurrentErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
```

With retryTemplate and recoverycallback

```java
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) throws IOException{
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(new RetryTemplate()); // 3 retries by default
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
            processingFailedErrorRecoverer().accept((ConsumerRecord<?, ?>) context.getAttribute("record"),
                    (Exception) context.getLastThrowable());
            return null;
        });

        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommitTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2000));
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L,3L));
        seekToCurrentErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(seekToCurrentErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
```

Log statements when consumer disconnects.

2.3.3-RELEASE ->
2020-08-10 10:51:23.881 23 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=xyz-consumer-group] Member consumer-1-1a0978c4-9ae6-45b9-8d9d-f3ddee081df9 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator  (id: 2147482644 rack: null)
2020-08-10 10:51:23.882 23 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=xyz-consumer-group] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions

2.5.4-RELEASE ->
2020-08-10 14:34:20.902 36 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | xyzconsumer-group] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xyz-consumer-group-1, groupId=xyz-consumer-group] Member consumer-xyz-consumer-group-1-8324f4e3-4ec3-4b34-b6af-c4ff01a0aa01 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator  (id: 2147482644 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

src/main/java

```
package com.orgname.gtb.cmng.kafka;
/**
 * @param <V> Original message type.
 * @param <T> Message type to be published.
 */
@Slf4j
public abstract class AbstractErrorRecoverer<V,T> implements BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> {
    private static final String LOGGER_NAME="ERRORHANDLER";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);       
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate; 
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate;

    protected AbstractErrorRecoverer(KafkaTemplate<String, T> kafkaTemplate,KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate=deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate;
        log.info("Recoverer initialized with alertDispatcher and kafkaTemplate.");
    }
    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void accept(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Exception e) {
        V original = (V) consumerRecord.value();
        // TODO Do other common things, like alerting etc. 
        List<Header> headers = this.enhanceHeaders(consumerRecord, e);
        
        DeserializationException deserEx = ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader(consumerRecord,
                ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER,  new LogAccessor(LOGGER_NAME));
        
        if(deserEx!=null){  
            ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> deserilizationErrorRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(getDeserializationErrorRecoveryTopic(), consumerRecord.partition(),
                    (String) consumerRecord.key(), deserEx.getData(), headers);
            if (deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate.isTransactional() && !deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate.inTransaction()) {
                deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(kafkaOperations -> {
                    this.publishDeserializationError(deserilizationErrorRecord, kafkaOperations);
                    return null;
                });
            } else {
                publishDeserializationError(deserilizationErrorRecord, deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate);
            }
        }
        else {
            T objectToPublish=messageToPublish(consumerRecord,e.getCause());
            ProducerRecord<String, T> pr = new ProducerRecord<>(getErrorTopic(), consumerRecord.partition(),
                    (String) consumerRecord.key(), objectToPublish, headers);

            if (kafkaTemplate.isTransactional() && !kafkaTemplate.inTransaction()) {
                kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(kafkaOperations -> {
                    this.publish(pr, kafkaOperations);
                    return null;
                });
            } else {
                publish(pr, kafkaTemplate);
            }
        }
    }

    private void publish(ProducerRecord<String, T> record, KafkaOperations<String, T> ops) {
        try {   
            ops.send(record).addCallback(stringTSendResult -> {
                log.debug("Successfully published message to dead letter topic");
            }, ex -> {
                log.error("error publishing to ERROR-Topic", ex);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error publishing to error-topic.", e);
        }
    }
    
    private void publishDeserializationError(ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record, KafkaOperations<String, byte[]> ops) {
        try {
            System.out.println("before pub to recovery topic");
            ops.send(record).addCallback(stringTSendResult -> {
                log.debug("Successfully published message to deserialization recovery topic.");
            }, ex -> {
                log.error("error publishing to deserialization recovery topic.", ex);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error publishing to deserialization recovery topic.", e);
        }
    }
    
    
    private List<Header> enhanceHeaders(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Exception exception) {
        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_ORIGINAL_TOPIC, record.topic().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_ORIGINAL_PARTITION, ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(record.partition()).array()));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_ORIGINAL_OFFSET, ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(record.offset()).array()));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP, ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(record.timestamp()).array()));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP_TYPE, record.timestampType().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_EXCEPTION_FQCN, exception.getClass().getName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, exception.getMessage().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.DLT_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE, this.getStackTraceAsString(exception).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        Header valDeserExceptionheader  =record.headers().lastHeader(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER);
        if (valDeserExceptionheader != null) {
            headers.add(valDeserExceptionheader);
        }
        return headers;
    }

    private String getStackTraceAsString(Throwable cause) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true);
        cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return  The error topic to which the notification should be sent.
     */
    protected abstract String getErrorTopic();
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return The error topic to which deserialization error should be sent.
     */
    protected abstract String getDeserializationErrorRecoveryTopic();
    
    /**
     * This method receives the original consumer record and throwable that was thrown by the listener 
     * Override this method to publish a different message (e.g. an enriched message to errorTopic).
     * By default the original message is returned which is published.
     * @param originalConsumerRecord The original consumer record. Same as that received by listener
     * @param t Throwable thrown by listner.
     * @return The expected message to be published.
     */
    protected T messageToPublish(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> originalConsumerRecord,Throwable t){
        return (T)originalConsumerRecord.value();
    }

}
```

src/test/java

```
package com.orgname.gtb.cmng.config;
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    // start of config for kafkatemplate that publishes a message 
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(producerProps(), new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
    }


    @Bean 
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
    //end of config for kafkatemplate that publishes a message
    
    // start of config for kafkatemplate that recovers deserialiazation error
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> deserializationErrorProducerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> deserializationErrorProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(deserializationErrorProducerProps());
    }


    @Bean 
    public KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(deserializationErrorProducerFactory());
    }
   // end of config for kafkatemplate that recovers deserialiazation error
    
    // config for kafkatemplate that publishes to deadlettertopic.
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> deadLetterKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
    
    // consumers config
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> getConsumerProps() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(
                getConsumerProps(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new StringDeserializer()
        );
    }

    // config for the error handler and its publisher to the dead letter topic

    @Bean   // the error recoverer
    public StringErrorRecovererImplementation processingFailedErrorRecoverer() {
        return new StringErrorRecovererImplementation(deadLetterKafkaTemplate(),deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommitTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2000));
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(processingFailedErrorRecoverer(),new FixedBackOff(0L,5L));
        seekToCurrentErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(seekToCurrentErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
    
    // config for the listener on the happy topic
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry() {
        KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry =
                new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry();
        return kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
    }

    // the listener
    @Bean
    public IntegrationTestMessageListener simpleStringMessageListener() {
        return new IntegrationTestMessageListener(kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry());
    }
```

src/test/java

```
 package com.orgname.gtb.cmng.kafka.integrationtest;
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}"})
    @EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 3, topics = {"${topics.happy}", "${topics.deadLetter}"})
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {IntegrationTestConfig.class})
    public class ErrorRecovererIntegrationTest {
    
         private static final String BAD_MESSAGE = "Poison message";
    
        @Value("${topics.happy}")
        private String happyTopic;
    
        @Value("${topics.deadLetter}")
        private String deadLetterTopic;
    
        @Autowired
        private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;
    
        @Autowired
        private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory; // will use the deadLetterConsumer factory in the TestKafkaConfig
    
    
        @Autowired
        protected KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
    
        @Autowired
        private IntegrationTestMessageListener listener;
    
        private Consumer<String, String> deadLetterConsumer;
    
        @Autowired
        private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            embeddedKafka.brokerProperty("controlled.shutdown.enable", true);
    
            for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
                log.debug("Listener container props:\n{}",messageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().toString());
                ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer, embeddedKafka.getPartitionsPerTopic());
            }
            deadLetterConsumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer();
            deadLetterConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(deadLetterTopic));
            deadLetterConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(0));
        }
    
        @After
        public void tearDown() {
            listener.clear();
        }
    
        @Test
        @DirtiesContext
        public void given_bad_message_should_publish_to_dead_letter_topic() throws Exception {
            IntStream.range(0, 6).forEach(i -> kafkaTemplate.send(happyTopic, i % 3,i+"", BAD_MESSAGE));
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords= KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(deadLetterConsumer);
            assertEquals(6,consumerRecords.count());
        }
```

src/test/java

```
package com.db.orgname.cmng.kafka.integrationtest;
/**
 * This listener will listen for "poison messages" and throw a runtime exception so the exception handling can be done.
 */
@Service
@Slf4j
public class IntegrationTestMessageListener {

    @Getter
    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Getter
    private Map<String,String> messages = new HashMap<>();

    public void clear() {
        messages.clear();
    }

    @Autowired
    public IntegrationTestMessageListener(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        log.debug("Created simple listener");
        this.registry = registry;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${topics.happy}")
    public void listen(@Payload String value, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        log.info("Simple listener received message --  key: {}, value: {}", key, value);
        if (value.toLowerCase().startsWith("poison")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        } else {
            messages.put(key, value);
        }

    }
```

src/test/java

```
package com.orgname.gtb.cmng.kafka.integrationtest;
@Getter
@Service
public class StringErrorRecovererImplementation extends AbstractErrorRecoverer<String,String> {

    public StringErrorRecovererImplementation(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate,KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate) {
        super(kafkaTemplate,deserializationErrorRecoveryKafkaTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getErrorTopic() {
        return "T-ERROR-TOPIC";
    }

    @Override
    protected String messageToPublish(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> orginal, Throwable t) {
        String originalString=(String)orginal.value();
        return originalString + t.getMessage();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDeserializationErrorRecoveryTopic() {
        return "T-DESERIALIZATION-ERROR-TOPIC";
    }
```

src/test/resources application.yml

```
topics:
  happy: T-HAPPY-TOPIC
  deadLetter: T-ERROR-TOPIC
  deserializationError: T-DESERIALIZATION-ERROR-TOPIC
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: latest
    producer:
      acks: all
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.orgname.gtb.cmng</groupId>
    <artifactId>nextgen-commons-error-handler</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>nextgen-commons-error-handler</name>
    <description>nextgen commons error handler</description> <!--fixme: Add proper description-->

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>

        <!--Test Dependencies-->
        <confluent.version>5.4.0</confluent.version>
        <mockito-core.version>2.9.0</mockito-core.version>
        <mockito-all.version>1.9.5</mockito-all.version>
        <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.13.2</assertj-core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>             
        </dependency>
        <!--Test Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!--TODO-changeme: Change the exclusions based on individual project requirements-->
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/entities/*.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/avro/*.class</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: >`Could be replicated with JUNIT as well. ` - please provide a complete small example to I can play with it to understand what is wrong. There is nothing in your configuration that should cause a long poll interval.

Comment: The retry template is no longer needed now that the STCEH has a `BackOff`.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for looking into it. Have provided the small example in the 'answer' section!! (Used answer section to provide more details).

Comment: I see you are new here. You must edit the question rather than adding more information in an "answer" (that's not an answer).

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for looking into it. Updated the question with additional information. (Having the same issue with original spring-boot running app as well that is connecting to actual cluster and schema registry) Couldn't post to public github due to banking organization restrictions/policies. Sorry about that!! :( . Issue could be replicated by placing the files in respective structures (i.e. src/main/java, src/main/test, src/main/resources and pom.xml) and running as JUNIT.

Comment: @GaryRussell Could you please let me know if you are able to replicate the issue with the provided JUNIT files. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look further - it's a pain to have to copy/paste all of the code; I will take a look today.

Comment: Your test is simply not waiting long enough; it's green for me when I change the sleep to `Thread.sleep(20000);`. Looking through the logs; it takes about 3 seconds to process each failure.

Comment: I fugured out why it is so slow. Since there are no more records in the topic, the outstanding (async) `fetch` will return no records so it times out (500ms) and the client sends the next `fetch` at that time. I reduced the `props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 50)` to 50ms and now it takes about 300ms to process each failure. I am not recommending this change in production (perhaps just in this test); I just wanted to understand what the delay was.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussel, after setting Thread.sleep(20000); the test case passes always. In the actual application the retries happens for 3 records (5 times for each)
and for 4th record around 2 or 3 times after which it doesn't progress and after 5mins (default max.poll.interval.ms) it disconnects from cluster. it takes about 15 seconds for for retires on 3 records, so could be with timing there as well.

Comment: During retires (which is taking about 15 seconds for 3 recoords) poll doesn't happen right. So something is causing a hang and poll not to happen for more than 5minutes causing error->
"sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator <xyz> due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.

Comment: Most likely, the thread is "stuck" in your code someplace; when it is in that state (no progress) take a thread dump. DEBUG logs might help too.

Comment: Also hoping the ordering from different partitions is not causing any issues 
(Which was cause of one of the issues earlier in older version : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1237#issuecomment-531928781,
which ofcourse if fixed in later versions)
(When running junit the order seems to be same always, so couldn't replicate that yet with junit).. 
And yes will look into from the app side why its getting stuck after about 15 seconds (after retrying and publishing to DLT for few records) causing the poll not to happen for more than 5minutes.

Comment: Right - that was fixed in 2.3 - see my answer below; when I run against a 3 broker cluster the retries cycle between the different partitions and we track the retry state by partition now; previously, we assumed we'd always get the failing record first. When I run against a single broker, we don't see that cycling; we always get the previous failure first.

Comment: I can confirm that its not spring-kafka issue and its application specific code (in custom recoverer, during the recovery process ) that is blocking the thread!! 
and preventing the subsequent poll(), which eventually is causing the consumer to leave the broker.
As we were using 2.2.6-RELEASE and had issue with multiple failed records from different partitions ->  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1237
thought subsequent version although had a fix, but has a different bug as the scenario is same!!. 
Thanks @GaryRussell for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a project that exhibits this behavior; I cannot reproduce it; everything works as expected with this application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63349172Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63349172Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63349172", topics = "so63349172")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorHandler eh() {
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                (rec, ex) -> System.out.println("Recovered " + ListenerUtils.recordToString(rec, true)),
                        new FixedBackOff(0, 2)) {

            @Override
            public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
                    Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {

                System.out.println("Failed " + ListenerUtils.recordToString(records.get(0), true));
                super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63349172").partitions(3).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 6).forEach(i -> template.send("so63349172", i % 3, null, "foo"));
        };
    }

}
```

I don't see anything in your configuration that would cause a rebalance.

Here are the results of my test (3 broker cluster)...

```
$ egrep '^(Failed|Recovered)' ../tmp/gg
Failed so63349172-1@0
Failed so63349172-2@0
Failed so63349172-0@0
Failed so63349172-1@0
Failed so63349172-2@0
Failed so63349172-0@0
Failed so63349172-1@0
Recovered so63349172-1@0
Failed so63349172-2@0
Recovered so63349172-2@0
Failed so63349172-0@0
Recovered so63349172-0@0
Failed so63349172-1@1
Failed so63349172-2@1
Failed so63349172-0@1
Failed so63349172-1@1
Failed so63349172-2@1
Failed so63349172-0@1
Failed so63349172-1@1
Recovered so63349172-1@1
Failed so63349172-2@1
Recovered so63349172-2@1
Failed so63349172-0@1
Recovered so63349172-0@1
```

Comment: As commented on the original question:
"I can confirm that its not spring-kafka issue and its application specific code (in custom recoverer, during the recovery process ) that is blocking the thread!! and preventing the subsequent poll(), which eventually is causing the consumer to leave the broker. As we were using 2.2.6-RELEASE and had issue with multiple failed records from different partitions -> github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1237 thought subsequent version although had a fix, but has a different bug as the scenario is same!!. Thanks @GaryRussell for all the help."